# postMessage is executed too late in code

Tags: web-worker, postmessage

I'm using postMessage to invoke parameters to a worker in JScript.

Unfortunatily it seems that postMessage is executed after main thread of the DOM is idle. I need a function to post while my code is running.

Background: Worker is holding a webSocket to communicate with server.

```js
function xy() {
   flag = 0;   

   while (!flag) {

      WORKER.postMessage(flag);

      //Problem: WORKER does not get post; Posts are invoked after while
      //Need something to break the rules
      GiveWorkerExecutionTimeOrDoEventsAndMessageStack();

      flag := CheckFlag();
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help :) !

EDIT:

I'll try to explain it nearer:

First of all I have a Worker Holding a web socket (separate js file):

```js
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8002/chat"; 

var websocket;

"use strict";

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    switch (e.data[0]) {
        case "run":
            runWebSocket();
            break;
        case "send":
            websocket.send(e.data[1]);
            break;
        case "addWait":
            break;
    }
}, false);

function runWebSocket() { 
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; 
    websocket.onopen = function (evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) }; 
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) }; 
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) }; 
}

function onOpen(evt) { 
    self.postMessage(['open', '']);
}

function onClose(evt) { 
    self.postMessage(['close', '']);
}

function onMessage(evt) {
    self.postMessage(['arrival', evt.data]);
} 

function onError(evt) { 
    self.postMessage(['error', evt.data]);
} 

function doSend(message) { 
    websocket.send(message); 
}
```

This Worker is running in a simple testing environment which has a button and a listener waiting for click Events.

I get my solution, if

a) sending of click data block is done
b) code is waiting to receive the answer of the server, click is processed. I would like to release the button only in this case

So I have made the button click listener in this way (see function EventCallback):

At the beginning I create a waiting key which will be stored in a Map. As Long as the map contains my waiting key, the click is not committed.

After posting the click content, I have my waiting loop. It should wait while my worker has sent the answer, processing should be committed.

Now I tell you the list of my problems:

1) even if there is a post to worker (click Event data) before the waiting Loop, the message is never reaching the worker. The worker gets the post after ending the Loop.

2) I'm not sure, what will happen with my check answer from Server, which has to be posted to main thread. I began trying with a setTimeout, but if no post is arriving back to my main thread, this is nonsense.

function EventCallback(evtName) {
    var WaitingKey;

```
evtName.stopPropagation();

WaitingThreadCtr++;
WaitingKey = "#" + WaitingThreadCtr;
WaitingThreads.set(WaitingKey, WaitingKey);

var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "controlevent", null);

// create the <submitter>, <name>, and text node
var submitterElement = doc.createElement("command");
var submitterData = doc.createElement("data");

Att = document.createAttribute("id");
Att.nodeValue = 'controlEvent';
submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

Att = document.createAttribute("threadid");
Att.nodeValue = WaitingKey;
submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

for (var p in evtName) {
    Att = document.createAttribute(p);
    Att.nodeValue = evtName[p];
    submitterData.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);
}

submitterElement.appendChild(submitterData);
doc.documentElement.appendChild(submitterElement);

doSend(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);

flag = false;
do {
    window.setTimeout(DoInterrupt, 100);
    if (WaitingThreads.get(WaitingKey) != WaitingKey) flag = true;
} while (flag == false);
```

}

This is a simple sample only, because I want to make this data protocol elsewhere in my code to simulate a function calling with ByRef Parameters.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8002/chat"; 

var webSocketWorker;

var output, outputW, outputH;
var WaitingThreads;
var WaitingThreadCtr;
var Timer;
var Interval;

"use strict";

function init() {
    output = document.getElementById("output");

    WaitingThreads = new Map();
    WaitingThreadCtr = 0;

    webSocketWorker = new Worker("websocket.js");

    webSocketWorker.addEventListener('message', WebSocketServerListen, false);

    webSocketWorker.postMessage(['run', '']);
}

function WebSocketServerListen(e) {
    switch (e.data[0]) {
        case 'arrival':
            dataArrival(e.data[1]);
            break;
        case 'error':
            break;
        case 'open':
            break;
        case 'close':
            break;
    }
}

function doSend(message) {
    webSocketWorker.postMessage(['send', message]);
}

function dataArrival(data) {

    var i, k, m, parser, xmlDoc, NodeCommand, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl;

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");

    NodeCommand = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("command");

    //DOM ist nun verfügbar
    for (i = 0; i < NodeCommand.length; i++) {
        switch (NodeCommand[i].childNodes[0].textContent) {
            case "event":
                id = NodeCommand[i].attributes.getNamedItem("threadid").value;
                WaitingThreads.delete(id);
                break;
            case "addControl":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandAddControl(NodeCommand[i]);
                break;
            case "addDiv":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandAddDiv(NodeCommand[i]);
                break;
            case "hideControl":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandShowHideControl(NodeCommand[i], false);
                break;
            case "showControl":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandShowHideControl(NodeCommand[i], true);
                break;
            case "resizeControl":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandResizeControl(NodeCommand[i]);
                break;
            case "setStyle":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandSetStyle(NodeCommand[i]);
                break;
            case "setProperty":
                //Tag einlesen; tag hat die Attribute id und html
                CommandSetProperty(NodeCommand[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}

function CommandAddDiv(CommandNode) {
    var k, m, e, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl, Dest, DivDest;

    Tag = CommandNode.getElementsByTagName("tag");

    for (k = 0; k < Tag.length; k++) {

        if (Tag[k].childNodes[0]) {
            El = Tag[k].childNodes[0].textContent;
        }

        id = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;

        DivEl = document.getElementById(id);
        if (DivEl) DivEl.parentNode.removeChild(DivEl);

        //div anlegen
        DivEl = document.createElement("div");
        DivEl.Control = new Control();

        Att = document.createAttribute("id");
        Att.nodeValue = id;
        DivEl.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        Att = document.createAttribute("class");
        Att.nodeValue = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("class").value;
        DivEl.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        Att = document.createAttribute("style");
        Att.nodeValue = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("style").value;
        DivEl.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        if (Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("visible").value == "0") {
            DivEl.style.display = "none";
        }

        El = Tag[k].getElementsByTagName("evt");
        for (e = 0; e < El.length; e++) {
            //Events binden
            DivEl.addEventListener(El[e].attributes.getNamedItem("name").value, EventCallback, false);
        }

        //append to id dest
        Dest = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("dest").value;
        if (Dest == '<root>') {
            output.appendChild(DivEl);
        } else {
            DivDest = document.getElementById(Dest);
            DivDest.appendChild(DivEl);
        }
    }
}

function Control() {
    this.AlignLeft = 0;
    this.AlignRight = 0;
    this.AlignTop = 0;
    this.AlignBottom = 0;
}

function CommandAddControl(CommandNode) {
    var k, m, e, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl, Dest, DivDest;

    Tag = CommandNode.getElementsByTagName("tag");

    for (k = 0; k < Tag.length; k++) {

        if (Tag[k].childNodes[0]) {
            El = Tag[k].childNodes[0].textContent;
        }

        id = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;

        DivEl = document.getElementById(id);
        if (DivEl) DivEl.parentNode.removeChild(DivEl);

        //div anlegen
        DivEl = document.createElement("div");

        Att = document.createAttribute("id");
        Att.nodeValue = id;
        DivEl.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        Att = document.createAttribute("style");
        Att.nodeValue = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("style").value;
        DivEl.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        TagEl = document.createElement(El);
        TagEl.textContent = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("html").value;

        //Tag-Node kann Att-Knoten haben
        NAtt = Tag[k].getElementsByTagName("att");

        for (m = 0; m < NAtt.length; m++) {
            Att = document.createAttribute(NAtt[m].attributes.getNamedItem("name").value);
            Att.nodeValue = NAtt[m].attributes.getNamedItem("value").value;
            TagEl.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);
        }
        DivEl.appendChild(TagEl);

        //Events binden
        El = Tag[k].getElementsByTagName("evt");
        for (e = 0; e < El.length; e++) {
            //Events binden
            TagEl.addEventListener(El[e].attributes.getNamedItem("name").value, EventCallback, false);
        }

        //append to id dest
        Dest = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("dest").value;
        if (Dest == '<root>') {
            output.appendChild(DivEl);
        } else {
            DivDest = document.getElementById(Dest);
            DivDest.appendChild(DivEl);
        }
    }
}

function CommandShowHideControl(CommandNode, ShowHide) {
    var k, m, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl, Dest, DivDest;

    Tag = CommandNode.getElementsByTagName("tag");

    for (k = 0; k < Tag.length; k++) {
        id = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;

        El = document.getElementById(id);
        if (El) {
            if (ShowHide == false) {
                El.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                El.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }
}

function CommandResizeControl(CommandNode) {
    var k, m, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl, Dest, DivDest;

    Tag = CommandNode.getElementsByTagName("tag");

    for (k = 0; k < Tag.length; k++) {
        id = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;

        El = document.getElementById(id);
        if (El) {
            El.style.left = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("left").value;
            El.style.top = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("top").value;
            El.style.width = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("width").value;
            El.style.height = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("height").value;
        }
    }
}

function CommandSetStyle(CommandNode) {
    var k, m, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl, Dest, DivDest;

    Tag = CommandNode.getElementsByTagName("tag");

    for (k = 0; k < Tag.length; k++) {
        id = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;

        El = document.getElementById(id);
        if (El) {
            El.style = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("style").value;
        }
    }
}

function CommandSetProperty(CommandNode) {
    var k, m, Tag, Att, El, id, htm, NAtt;
    var DivEl, DivStyle, TagEl, Dest, DivDest;

    Tag = CommandNode.getElementsByTagName("tag");

    for (k = 0; k < Tag.length; k++) {
        id = Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;

        El = document.getElementById(id);
        if (El) {
            eval("El." + Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("property").value + " = " + Tag[k].attributes.getNamedItem("value").value);
        }
    }
}

function TimeoutFunc() {
    //Timer = setTimeout(TimeoutFunc, 50);
}

function WaitInterval() {
    Timer = setTimeout(TimeoutFunc, 10);
}

function EventCallback(evtName) {
    var WaitingKey;

    evtName.stopPropagation();

    WaitingThreadCtr++;
    WaitingKey = "#" + WaitingThreadCtr;
    WaitingThreads.set(WaitingKey, WaitingKey);

    var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "controlevent", null);

    // create the <submitter>, <name>, and text node
    var submitterElement = doc.createElement("command");
    var submitterData = doc.createElement("data");

    Att = document.createAttribute("id");
    Att.nodeValue = 'controlEvent';
    submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

    Att = document.createAttribute("threadid");
    Att.nodeValue = WaitingKey;
    submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

    for (var p in evtName) {
        Att = document.createAttribute(p);
        Att.nodeValue = evtName[p];
        submitterData.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);
    }

    submitterElement.appendChild(submitterData);
    doc.documentElement.appendChild(submitterElement);

    doSend(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);
    
    flag = false;
    do {
        window.setTimeout(DoInterrupt, 100);
        if (WaitingThreads.get(WaitingKey) != WaitingKey) flag = true;
    } while (flag == false);
}

function DoInterrupt() {
    
}

function WindowResize(evtName) {
    var w, h;
    w = output.clientWidth;
    h = output.clientHeight;
    
    if ((outputW != w) || (outputH != h)) {

        outputW = w;
        outputH = h;

        var Att;
        var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "windowResize", null);

        // create the <submitter>, <name>, and text node
        var submitterElement = doc.createElement("command");
        Att = document.createAttribute("id");
        Att.nodeValue = 'windowResize';
        submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        Att = document.createAttribute("width");
        Att.nodeValue = w;
        submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        Att = document.createAttribute("height");
        Att.nodeValue = h;
        submitterElement.attributes.setNamedItem(Att);

        doc.documentElement.appendChild(submitterElement);

        doSend(doc.documentElement.innerHTML);

    }
}

function writeToScreen(message) { 
    var pre = document.createElement("p"); 
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word"; 
    pre.innerHTML = message; 
    output.appendChild(pre); 
} 

window.addEventListener("load", init, false); 
window.addEventListener("resize", WindowResize, false);

</script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<html>

<head>
<title>WebSocket Test</title> 
</head>

<body>
<h2>WebSocket Test</h2> 

<div id="output"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide some more information and how are you receiving the message in main thread

Comment: All I can tell you is that this would work in normal javascript. I just tested it...

Answer (score 0):

As I have been working on multithreading js api ([OODK-JS](https://github.com/GOMServices/oodk-js-oop-for-js)) I could answer this:

it is not possible to break an infinite loop with an async call (including setTimout) as the callback function is executed only once the thread is free of charge. Running an infinite loop monopolize the thread and all async callback are delayed until the loop is done which never occured

```
flag = false;
do {
    // DoInterrupt is never called as the do/while loop is monopolizing the current thread 
    window.setTimeout(DoInterrupt, 100);
    if (WaitingThreads.get(WaitingKey) != WaitingKey) flag = true;
} while (flag == false);
```